# Einstein Analytics dashboard - filter one widget only

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards

Is there a work-around to implement multi-select pick list type of filter which would affect one specific widget only , on the dashboard? (ie, as oppose to global filters, which affect all widgets linked to the same dataset)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a List widget. Either use a static step in the background or an existing dataset (then you have to deselect, that the selection is broadcasted).

Then in a second step use a column binding in the query of the widget which it is supposed to filter:

```
{{column(static_Details.selection, [\"value\"]).asObject()}}
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick! :)